# Unhandled exception: FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I have some problems reading file in java:
my file is for example:

```
3,4
2
6
4
1
7
3
8
9
```

where first line 3 and 4 are the lenght of array A and B and then the element of each array.
I made this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Progetto  {

    public static void main(String args[])
      {
// Open the file that is the first 
// command line parameter

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prova.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine = br.readLine(); // step 1

            if (strLine != null) {
              String[] delims = strLine.split(","); // step 2

              // step 3
              int[] a = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[0])];
              int[] b = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[1])];

              // step 4
              for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

              // step 5
              for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++)
                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

              br.close(); // step 6

              // step 7
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
            }
        }
      }
```

But it gives me error:
-Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException (line 11)
-Unhandled exception type IOException (lines 15 26 30 32)
but i don't know why. Someone can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: this line `FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prova.txt");` gave the exception while runtime, try to add `try-catch` block.

Comment: Is this the output that you are expecting                             [2, 6, 4]
[1, 7, 3, 8]

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Answer (score 14):

Change the way your main method throws `IOException`. Since these operations may cause either `FileNotFoundException` or `IOException`.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    }
```

Or add a `try-catch` block

```
   try {
        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prova.txt");
        String strLine = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
        // handle exception correctly.
    }
```

After all these thing make sure that file is exist.

Comment: I got an error because it was expecting my function to return something and I fixed it by replacing `e.printStackTrace();` with `throw new RuntimeException(e);`. (I also had to `import java.lang.RuntimeException`)

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add try-catch blocks for the unhandled exceptions.
This happens because `FileInputStream` throws `FileNotFoundException` which is a checked exception You can [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) here more)

The same issue happens here with

```
String strLine = br.readLine()
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add `throws IOException` after main method's signature

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
```

**For your Next Question :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Progetto {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int a[] = null;
        int b[] = null;
        try {
            // Open the file that is the first
            // command line parameter

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prova.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine = br.readLine(); // step 1

            if (strLine != null) {
                String[] delims = strLine.split(","); // step 2

                // step 3
                a = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[0])];
                b = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[1])];

                // step 4
                for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
                    a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                // step 5
                for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++)
                    b[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

                br.close();
            }// step 6
        } catch (Exception e) {// Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        // step 7
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Always catch the most specific error possible. 2. In the code you gave, there's no reason to both catch Exception and throw IOException. 3. If you're going to give code as an example of what to do, it should also be closing the streams properly.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Ruchira, i made this

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Progetto  {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    }
      {
          try {
// Open the file that is the first 
// command line parameter

            FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream("prova.txt");
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
            String strLine = br.readLine(); // step 1


            if (strLine != null) {
              String[] delims = strLine.split(","); // step 2

              // step 3
              int[] a = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[0])];
              int[] b = new int[Integer.parseInt(delims[1])];

              // step 4
              for (int i=0; i < a.length; i++)
                a[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

              // step 5
              for (int i=0; i < b.length; i++)
                b[i] = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

              br.close(); }// step 6
          }catch (Exception e){//Catch exception if any
                System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
                }
              // step 7
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
              System.out.println(Arrays.toString(b));
            }

        }
```

But now at the end i have this error:

> a cannot be resolved to a variable

and the same for b. 
But i `import java.util.Arrays;`

Comment: Please declare the int array a and b, before starting the try block as I have shown you in my answer.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Answer (score 0):

```
void addRule(String content){
    FileOutputStream outStream = null;
    try {
        outStream = this.openFileOutput("BlockList", Context.MODE_APPEND);
        outStream.write(("\n"+content).getBytes());
        outStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```